# Write conflict in Dynamo

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, distributed, key-value, distributed-system

Imaging that there are two clients client1 and client2, both writing the same key. This key has three replicas named A, B, C. A first receives client1's request, and then client2', while B receives client2's request, and then client1's. Now A and B must be inconsistent with each other, and they cannot resolve conflict even using Vector Clock. Am I right?

If so, it seems that it is easy to occur write conflict in dynamo. Why so many open source projects based on dynamo's design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't talk about HBase, but I can about Cassandra, which is inspired in Dynamo.

If that happens in Cassandra, the most recent key wins.

Cassandra uses coordinator nodes (which can be any node), that receive the client requests and resends them to all replica nodes. Meaning each request has its own timestamp.

Imagine that Client2 has the most recent request, miliseconds after Client1.

- Replica A receives Client1, which is saved, and then Client2, which is saved over Client1 since Client2 is the most recent information for that key.
- Replica B receives Client2, which is saved, and then Client1, which is rejected since has an older timestamp.

Both replicas A and B have Client2, the most recent information, and therefore are consistent.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Dynamo and are worried about race conditions (which you should be if you're using lambda)

You can check conditionals on putItem or updateItem, if the condition fails

e.g. during getItem the timestamp was 12345, add conditional that timestamp must equal 12345, but another process updates it, changes the timestamp to 12346, your put/update should fail now, in java for example, you can catch ConditionalCheckFailedException, you can do another get item, apply your changes on top, then resubmit the put/update

---

To prevent a new item from replacing an existing item, use a conditional expression that contains the attribute_not_exists function with the name of the attribute being used as the partition key for the table. Since every record must contain that attribute, the attribute_not_exists function will only succeed if no matching item exists.

For more information about PutItem, see Working with Items in the Amazon DynamoDB Developer Guide.

Parameters:
putItemRequest - Represents the input of a PutItem operation.
Returns:
Result of the PutItem operation returned by the service.
Throws:
ConditionalCheckFailedException - A condition specified in the operation could not be evaluated.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDB.html#putItem-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.PutItemRequest-